# Why does my autoencoder generate some wierd pixels while reconstructing?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, autoencoder, generative-adversarial-network

I have been working on the problem of deblurring an image using GAN. My generator is an autoencoder which should take a blurry image as input and output a de-blurred image. The results are good but the reconstructed image is containing some weird pixels.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsTFd.jpg The middle column in each image is my output. Can someone help me understand why am I getting those weird artifacts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably caused by overflow(underflow) if those pixels' RGB values are negative or over 255 (assuming 8 bits for each channel) after decoding. To solve that, simply overwrite those values with 0 and 255 before showing the images.